# why I am getting Class not found exception

Tags: java, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I am using `DeferredTextImpl` Class and eclipse does not seems to complain about it but when I run my project I get run time exception `.... Class not found exception for DeferredTextImpl ..`

When I searched for the class file, I found it in `rt.jar` which should certainly be on the class path.  I also checked the build path in project `properties->Java build path` and could see JRE System Library at the very bottom. when I expanded that. I could see `rt.jar`. which means it is on the class path, right ?

Why am I getting this error ?

Comment: Are you working on a J2SE application or an J2EE application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the version of your Xerces jar for your runtime versus you compile time classes. Make sure have a Xerces2 jar at runtime. I doubt the the class in the rt.jar is the same class your application is looking for.

Comment: This is what I could find...                                       //  Compiled from DeferredTextImpl.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)

Comment: Remember classes can have the same name the Fully Qualified identifier is classloader+package+name. It is likely there are multiple DeferredTextImpl.class files. Find the xerces.jar and make sure its on your runtime path. I bet you will be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: I found the file... and could see that the particular file was not on the build path... I could not see the little green icon next to it.. when I right clicked and when to build path .. there was an option to 'Add to Build Path'.. just did that ... now will run... fingers crossed !

Comment: build path is different from run path. You need to supply the jar on the class path at runtime. `java -cp <where to find your jar>`

Comment: it actually worked ! so I am not getting the class not found exception anymore... but I am getting class cast exception :( but you deserve accept

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between the *build path* in Eclipse and the *classpath* when you run your code. The build path is used to compile your code. The classpath is what your application has when it runs.

The build path is configured with *Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path*

The class path is configured with *Run -> Run Configurations -> Classpath*

In your case, you should also check (as others mentioned), if the *JRE* tab under *Run Configurations* points to the same JRE as in your build path.

Answer (score 1):

This class is part of a specific DOM implementation (Apache Xerces). It's not part of the public Java API, and if you do in fact find it in one JVM's runtime class library, this is no guarantee it'll be in others. If you need to explicitly work with Xerces, then you need to explicitly include the Xerces libraries on your runtime class path.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try running the code by explicitly adding rt.jar with -jar option while running the code? If this works then it means that the rt.jar in eclipse is not on classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project > java build path > Libraries 
remove JRE and add library pointing to JDK folder which in my case is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55.
But before that do the same thing with java installed JRE as well.
Windows > java > installed JRE .
Hope this will help